# AngularJS: How can I $setPristine after submit the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I want some input element be $setPristine when I submit the form. Because after I submit the form, I would empty the model bind to the input element, in case of user can totally input something new again. But once I empty the model, the input element would empty too, so the validate information would show, for `required`.

So I want $setPristine after submit the form. I figure out two ways:

**One:**

I use expression in the `ng-submit`, like:

```
<form ng-controller="FormController" name="userForm" ng-submit="userForm.$valid?submitForm(),userForm.keywordsInput.$setPristine(): ''">
```

But this syntax seems wring because angular report error information in the console.

**Two**

I could pass form to the submit function, then $setPristine in the submit function :

```
$scope.submit = function (form) {
    form.keywordsInput.$setPristine()
}
```

But I also don't this is a good practice, because in the angular official reference site, it suggest:

> Do not use controllers to:Manipulate DOM.

Is this way a kind of manipulating DOM?

So is there a better way to achieve this job？

Comment: setting pristine is not manipulating the dom, it's updating the data model appropriately. Does your form tag have a `name`? Are you using `controllerAs` syntax? If named properly that name is already available in controller even without passing it in function

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, the form has its own name and controller, which I just ignored and now I edit them back

Comment: so inside controller you already have `$scope.userForm`. Personally i would remove the commands from the view. Inside submit function can reset whole form with `$scope.userForm.$setPristine()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue logging undefined $setPristine(). But,in the view it works.

```
<button class="button button-stable button-block " type="submit" ng-click="register(registerData);formName.$setPristine();"> Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form, you must have set some function to run in the "ng-click" attribute

Add formName.$setPristine(); after it